# Calculate numbers between two date with all month = 30 days

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I'm looking for a way to count the numbers of day between two date respecting 30days by month ( even in february, month at 31).

There is some solution in SQL but i'm looking for a solution in c# if possible.
Any idea please ?

**Example :** ( DATE US )

01/01/2016 to 05/31/2016 = 150 days instead of 150.

because there is in this case 5 month, so 5*30 = 150.
All month are based on 30days in my case.

**Other example :**

From 01/16/2016 to 07/17/2016 = 182 instead of 183 (15+30+30+30+30+30+17)

Comment: Looks quite strange, why you want to challenge the calendars and make all months as 30 days? Adding some more detail as to what you are trying to achieve will help in understanding it.

Comment: You can get the month number of a DateTime object which will return a number from 1 to 12.  You may need to also look at year if you are counting months from November to February.

Comment: There are so many special cases to consider that there is no hope of answering this question in any sensible way. At least give some input and expected output for the corner cases you can think of yourself.

Comment: Are the two input dates given in your new calendar system, or in our normal calendar system?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What are you trying to count exactly? The number of days? Can you give us an example with the expected output?

Comment: Those aren't the special cases though. One of the special cases that make this question hard to answer is e.g. 01/31/2016 to 02/01/2016. There are other special cases.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni are you sure that in your second example it's not 181?

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do seems like the same calendar used for the financial market. Here's a solution implementing the [30E/360 ISDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention#30E.2F360) calculation method as it was implemented in the [demo XLS](http://www.isda.org/c_and_a/trading_practice.html) they provide on their website (30/360 Day Count Conventions):

```
var start = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
var finish = new DateTime(2016, 05, 31);


var d1 = start.Day == 31 ? 30 : start.Day;
var d2 = finish.Day == 31 && (start.Day == 30 || start.Day == 31) ? 30 : finish.Day;
// actualDaysDiff will be 151 as expected
var actualDaysDiff = (finish - start).TotalDays;
// using the new method newDaysDiff will be 150
int newDaysDiff = ((360 * (finish.Year - start.Year)) + (30 * (finish.Month - start.Month)) + (d2 - d1));
```

I'm getting the correct result for your other example (which, I think, should be 181 days).

For more information on this topic check the following:

1. [360-day calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360-day_calendar)
2. [C# for Financial Markets](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470030089.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var months = endDate.Month - startDate.Month - 1;
var startDateDayes = 30 - startDate.Day;
startDateDayes =startDateDayes ==-1 ? 0 : startDateDayes;//for 31 month days
var endDateDayes = endDate.Day;
var totalDays = startDateDayes + endDateDayes + months * 30;
if (endDate.Year > startDate.Year)
{
    totalDays += 360 * (endDate.Year - startDate.Year);
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int GetDays(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    int newDaysDiff = ((360 * (end.Year - start.Year)) + (30 * ((end.Month - start.Month) == 0 ? 0 : (end.Month - start.Month) - 1)));
    int j = 0;
    if (start.Month == end.Month && start.Year == end.Year) {
        if (start.Day == 1 && end.Day == 31) {
            j = (end.Day - start.Day);
        }
        else {
            j = (end.Day - start.Day) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (start.Day == 1) {
            j = j + 30;
        }
        else {
            j = j + DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month) - start.Day + 1;
        }
        if (end.Day == 30 || end.Day == 31) {
            j = j + 30;
        }
        else {
            j = j + end.Day;
        }
    }
    newDaysDiff = newDaysDiff + j;
    return newDaysDiff;
}
```

Comment: function provide date diff between two date with considering full month as 30 day